# Date of Birth is restricted till year "1980" in json

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on MVC project in which I am facing below issue

"Date of Birth is restricted till year "1980" in json"

I don't have any knowledge of JSON.

It is calling below function

```html
if (dateObject == null) {
        return "";
    }
    else {
        var jsonDate = dateObject;
        var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
        
        return ($.datepicker.formatDate(DATE_FORMAT, date));
    }
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to restrict birth dates in you JSON to be before 1980? (In which case what creates the JSON?). Or do you mean the JSON you are sent will only contain birth dates before 1980? (In which case just parse the dates: such a restriction does not affect how you convert the JSON text into a JavaScript `Date`).

Comment: No. I mean my datepicker calender is showing only the year upto 1980, which should not be the case. It should allow user to select the year which is below 1980 as well. But as it is showing only upto 1980, user is restricted till that year.

Answer (score 0):

Date of Birth is got by your Javascript and not by JSON. Please check the input fields and validation functions of Javascript. Its functional validation written by developer rather than technical one.